# Buscar con regex en MySQL ignorando acentos, mayúsculas y minúsculas

Tags: mysql, regex

Necesito adaptar una expresión regular para realizar búsquedas en un módulo del sistema.
He validado la expresión regular en "https://regex101.com/". Y funciona perfectamente, este REGEX lo recrea dinámicamente con PHP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si realizo la búsqueda por ejemplo de `"aba"`, necesito que en MySQL busque "`aba`, `ábä`, `âbà`, ..." (insensible a mayúscula y minúscula).

La expresión regular que se muestra es simplemente un replace, no necesito código PHP. Busco una adaptación de este regex a MySQL.

```
/[a|ãàáâäåAÃÀÁÂÄÅ]b[a|ãàáâäåAÃÀÁÂÄÅ]/g
```

Comment: Hola DMA, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Dices que necesitas una adaptacion de la [tag:regex] a [tag:mysql]... pero, ¿qué has probado?. Para que podamos ayudarte has te mostrar tus intentos y los errores o problemas que has tenido. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: @lois6b necesito adaptar una expresión regular funcional de JS y PHP, a MySQL.
Y Mariano sí es exactamente lo que busco. Lo de inglés disculpa pensé que había formulado la pregunta en el global, no me fijé en la URL(es.stackoverflow.com).
Gracias por las acotaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay nada para adaptar. Simplemente

```
select campo
  from tabla
 where campo REGEXP '[aãàáâäåAÃÀÁÂÄÅ][bB][aãàáâäåAÃÀÁÂÄÅ]'
```

- Eliminé los `|` que estaban mal.
- Reemplacé `b` por `[bB]`.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6df1a/1/0

---

Sin embargo, si te interesa que todas las comparaciones de texto se hagan sin considerar diacríticos (acentos) mayúsculas o minúsculas, no hay forma de establecer un modificador en la expresión regular. Para eso deberías modificar la [**`collation`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html) (intercalación) en MySQL. Lo preferible es hacerlo en toda la tabla. Al crearla:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla
    (
      `id` int, `campo` varchar(30)
    ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci';
;
```

```
select id, campo
  from tabla
 where campo like '%aba%'
-- O también:
-- where campo regexp 'aba'
```

- Con `utf8` estás usando las equivalencias de caracteres en Unicode, que incluyen las formas con diacríticos. `ci` significa *case insensitive* (ignorar mayúsculas/minúsculas).

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc9878/1/0

O modificando la tabla existente:

```
alter table tabla convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

O incluso modificando toda la base de datos (no solamente la tabla):

```
alter database Nombre character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Pero, si no quisieras cambiar nada, podrías cambiarla sólo para tu consulta, con algo como:

```
where campo like '%aba%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

- Teniendo en cuenta que esto ignora el índice de la tabla, por lo que podría hacerse más lento. Alternativamente, si estás con un índice en ese campo podrías generar un campo anexo `campo_busqueda` con la `collation` correcta.
- Para modificar la `collation` en una sola columna:

  ```
  alter table tabla modify campo varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59efe9/1/0

Comment: Tu respuesta era lo que necesitaba. (No exactamente)
Mi solución fue ir directamente a alterar todas las tablas, sin REGEX.
No recordaba el collate por eso digo que era lo que necesitaba me enfoqué mucho en algo mas complicado.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si, eso es lo que pasa por tener tantas horas enfocado en algo sin consultarlo.
Simplemente utilicé un alter schema.
ALTER SCHEMA <table> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: @DMAVE Claro. Agregué la información para completar la respuesta.